# Time Derivative of Dynamical System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose I have a dynamical system of the form
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)
$$
Most of the frameworks I am familiar with for analyzing such systems revolve around finding the fixed points $x^*$ where $f(x^*) = 0$. However, suppose this system does not have any fixed points. So I'm wondering whether you can look at its derivative, i.e
$$
g(x) = \frac{d^2x}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(x)
$$
Can we get any interesting information by finding the fixed points of $g(x)$? I am thinking that in some cases a system may not have steady states in $x$, but it may achieve steady states in the velocities of $x$. An example might be an engine, where the engine is net producing stuff, but it might stabilize to a constant rate of production.

Also, I believe that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the Jacobian, so if $f(x)$ is never 0, we just need to find the kernel of the Jacobian.

Ideas and references would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If we are to write this explicitly, then for each coordinate $x_i$, we need to have $\sum_j (\partial f_i / \partial x_j) f_j = 0$ so that its velocity along that axis does not change. Graphically, the  mass has to move along the contour of the velocity (perpendicular to the slope). Just my speculation, hope this helps!